# Java 8u161/8u162 makes Swing app use CPU

Tags: java, swing

When running a Swing application on 8u161 or 8u162 and focus is in a JTextField and you switch to another application (like Chrome) and back to the application CPU usage grows to 15% on my 8 core Windows 10 PC (as if an entire core is busy processing events).

Just run the application and switch a couple of times.
If I click on the tab in the tabbed pane CPU usage drops to 0 as expected.

```
public class Test {
  public static void main(String... args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
      JFrame f = new JFrame("Test");
      JTabbedPane tp = new JTabbedPane();
      tp.addTab("tab 1", new JTextField(20));
      f.add(tp);
      f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      f.pack();
      f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      f.setVisible(true);
    });
  }
}
```

I have tried to look at the event queue to see what happens and it looks a lot like the last event gets processed again and again

If I add this to the above program I get a lot of java.awt.event.InvocationEvent[INVOCATION_DEFAULT,runnable=sun.awt.windows.WInputMethod ...

```
Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemEventQueue().push(new EventQueue(){
  @Override protected void dispatchEvent(AWTEvent event) {
    System.out.println(event);
    super.dispatchEvent(event);
  }
});
```

Works OK on 8u151, 8u152 and 9.0.4

I have a lot of customers that are upgrading to 161 and get this problem so any suggestions for a workaround is much appreciated.
[I have filed a bug with Oracle](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=JDK-8195830)

JProfiler shows this:
[image]

Seems to work OK on 8u172 b02

According to [openjdk](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/awt-dev/2018-January/013479.html) this was introduced by  [8184016](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=JDK-8184016) and fixed by [8183504](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=JDK-8183504)

Comment: Run a profiler and see what it says.

Comment: I have the same issue in my program, and also in a SSCCE similiar to yours. Based on my observations (the AWT-EventQueue-0 thread constantly running while CPU usage was high, and it only happening when a JTextField is the first thing to gain focus when the window gains focus) it seems to be the same issue, and I would also be very interested in a good workaround until this is (hopefully soon) fixed.

Comment: Doesn't seem to happen on linux.

Comment: 172 EA solves this bug. See [Bug Id 8195830](https://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=8195830).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are your customers using input methods? If you don't need input methods enabled, I suggest that you could disable it.

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
              JFrame f = new JFrame("Test");
              JTabbedPane tp = new JTabbedPane();
              JTextField tf = new JTextField();
              tf.enableInputMethods(false); // disable IM
              tp.addTab("tab 1", tf);
              f.add(tp);
              f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
              f.pack();
              f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
              f.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably pretty ugly, but it's a workaround I created based on my observations on when the bug occurs. I'm sure it's possible to create a better workaround with better understanding of why exactly the bug occurs in the first place.

It basicially prevents any `JTextComponent` from being focused as the first thing after the window gets focused, transfers focus to another component (`upFocusCycle(component)` for me puts in on the frame/dialog) and then transfers it back the the `JTextComponent`. I don't know if this will work in every case or maybe even break something, but it seems to work for me. Use at your own risk obviously.

```
public class JTextFieldTest {

    public static final void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            // Install workaround, without this the bug occurs
            installTextComponentFocusWorkaround();

            JFrame window = new JFrame("Test");
            window.setLocationByPlatform(true);
            window.add(new JButton("Button"), BorderLayout.CENTER);
            window.add(new JTextField(), BorderLayout.SOUTH);
            window.pack();
            window.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            window.setVisible(true);
        });
    }

    public static void installTextComponentFocusWorkaround() {
        KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager().addVetoableChangeListener(new VetoableChangeListener() {

            private boolean rejectNext = false;
            private JComponent target;

            @Override
            public void vetoableChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) throws PropertyVetoException {
                if (evt.getNewValue() != null) {
                    if (evt.getPropertyName().equals("focusOwner")) {
                        if (evt.getNewValue() instanceof JTextComponent) {
                            if (rejectNext) {
                                JComponent component = (JComponent) evt.getNewValue();
                                KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager().upFocusCycle(component);
                                target = component;
                                System.out.println("Rejected JTextComponent focus");
                                throw new PropertyVetoException("Rejected JTextComponent focus", evt);
                            }
                        } else {
                            rejectNext = false;
                            if (target != null) {
                                System.out.println("Temp focus: " + evt.getNewValue());
                                target.requestFocus();
                                target = null;
                            }
                        }
                    } else if (evt.getPropertyName().equals("focusedWindow")) {
                        System.out.println("Window focused");
                        rejectNext = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }

}
```

I also tried things like clearing focus altogether or only throwing a `PropertyVetoException`, but only actually focusing someting else before the `JTextComponent` seemed to work.

I'm looking for `JTextComponent` because the bug occured for me with both `JTextField` and `JTextArea`, although I'm not sure if other classes are affected as well.

Comment: Just tried your workaround. It seems to work at first, but if I type some letters in the textfield and the move the frame around, the CPU usage comes back.